# Adding 2 years to the Current Date in Javascript

Tags: javascript

If the software I am using asks for a javascript entry for an action, do I need to enter the entire javascript (function, brackets, etc.,) or just the syntax for what I'm trying to do?
I want to display the current date, except +2 years from "today's" date. Any Snippets I add don't seem to work (mostly, they return a "0")

Comment: What "software" are you using?

Comment: You can try using momentJS `.add(2, 'years')` method. More on this here: https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: its based on the software, few accept function and "statement". and few only accepts statement alone

Comment: No this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `getFullYear()`, `getMonth()` and `getDate()` and then you can modify those values accordingly and create a new Date with those modified value:

```js
function modifyDate(addYears){
  var date = new Date();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var month = date.getMonth();
  var day = date.getDate();
  var res = new Date(year + addYears, month, day)
  return res;
}

var addYears = 2
var res = modifyDate(addYears);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I think you could do `var res = date.setFullYear(year+addYears);` and skip getting the month and day

Comment: @AndrewBone That's good but just in case OP needs to manipulate the month and day then it is flexible at that context